# Empty driverClassName in pool properties during initializing

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm getting weird behavior of Spring JDBC with Tomcat and Oracle db. During initializing of db connection (from pool which is configured in Tomcat) the `driverClassName` is empty, so I get `ClassNotFoundException`. I'm not sure why it is empty, the initialization during Tomcat startup looks OK. All ten connection have been initialized OK, but then a few hours later, the `driverClassName` is empty. Well, even the URL is empty.

I enabled debugging of 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool' to FINE to get more info, but no luck.

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver Instantiating driver using class:  [url=]
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass Attempting to load class[] from java.net.URLClassLoader@10bbd20a
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass Attempting to load class[] from ParallelWebappClassLoader

org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver Unable to instantiate JDBC driver.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class:  from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@10bbd20a;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: told-integration-tool
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@10bbd20a
```

I'm using:

- Tomcat: 9.0.69
- Spring JDBC: 5.3.22
- ojdbc: 12.1.0.2.0

What do you think? Where could a problem?